# How to use the datepicker in html contenteditable element

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker, contenteditable

Hi I am using datepicker plugin in contenteditable element.Have to select the datepicker value in the  contenteditable div.
Html:

```
<div class="sample">
  <input name="date" class="datepicker-input"  />
  <div class="date1" contentEditable="true">test</div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$('.date').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find('.datepicker-input').focus();
  $(".datepicker-input").blur(function(){
    var valuew = $('.datepicker-input').val() ;
    console.log(valuew);
    $(".date1").val(valuew);
  });
});
```

the datepicker value is not assign to the div.If i use type hidden to datepicker is datepiker calender not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
    
    $('#thedate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
         onSelect: function(dateText) {
     $('#dateContainer').text(dateText);
        console.log(dateText);
        }
        
    });
    
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
Shown Date : <div id="dateContainer" type="button" > currentData </div>
<input id="thedate" type="text" /><br />
<input id="thesubmit" type="button" value="Submit" />
```

Well, Below is the  `jquery date picker` with editable textbox.

***JS Fiddle with date picker:-***
http://jsfiddle.net/vikash2402/8w8v9/1989/

***JS Fiddle with date picker and div:-***
http://jsfiddle.net/vikash2402/8w8v9/1990/

***Hoping this will help you :)***

Comment: Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: One more clarification if you know please help
How to use the input field inside the table <td> for using datepicker inside <td>
if i used inside the table <td> but input field not came inside the table.

Comment: can you just create your html layout here so that i can provide you exact solution. However don't worry it is doable.. just give some more details about it.. or simlply post a new question and give me the link...

Comment: Hi @ Developerrr thanks for the reply i posted other questine here is the link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39874737/if-it-is-possible-to-focus-the-hidden-input-field
it reflects the the above code if you know please comment for the question.

Comment: I have added an answer to the question check if that useful for you.

Comment: Hi @ Developerrr could you know please comment for the question reg:bootstrap datepicker.here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40265208/datepicket-is-not-working-while-replacing-bootstrap-datepicket-with-js-datepicke

Comment: Hi @ Developerrrcould you know please comment for the question reg:datatable plugin .here is the link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40971532/how-to-sort-the-datetime-field-in-datatable-plugin-in-php

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery `$(".date1").text(valuew);`

or using DOM

```
document.getElementsByClassName("date1").textContent=valuew;
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector for your event -

```
$('.date').click(function() {
```

references a class that doesn't exist... Shouldn't you be using:

```
$('.date1').click(function() {
```

Also shouldn't you be setting your DIV value with .html() and not .val()?