# Is it possible to focus on the hidden input field?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker, html-table

How to trigger the hidden input field when we click the parent element.When i use the hidden field is not worked.
Here is my html code:

```
<table>
<th colspan="2">Date</th>
<td id="dateContainer" > currentData </td>
<td><input id="thedate" type="hidden" /></td>
<table>
```

jquery code:

```
$(function(){
 $(this).click(function() {
 $(this).children().children().find('.datepicker-input').focus();
 });
});
```

Comment: hidden fields are not rendered in the dom. you cannot focus them. you can style a normal text input to be hidden (via CSS) and then trigger to display it and focus

Comment: we done only by using css visibality hidden?

Comment: Why you want focus hidden input?

Comment: <input id="thedate" type="text" type="hidden" /> is Wrong in your code

Comment: @sojtin want to focus the date picker while click this #dateContainer id.

Comment: @Samudrala Ramu  i edit the code typing error.

Comment: It is quite a XY problem. Ask question about your expected behaviour, not the workaround you think would work. And FYI, the HTML markup you provide is invalid AFAIK

Comment: Use the datepicker events api to update hidden field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think I understood your query what exactly you want to achieve.

you want to show the `datepicker` without visible container. It seems **impossible** because whenever you load datepicker it need some CSS property like `left, positioning` and all. and if datepicker container is hidden it will throw you exception.

Below is another way by which you can achieve this. Create an empty html element and add date picker to it.

Here is the working code; change your html structure accordingly.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vikash2402/8w8v9/2030/

```js
$('#showDateContainer').click(function(){
$("#showDateItem").show && $("#showDateItem").show();
$('#showDateItem').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
         onSelect: function(dateText) {
     $('#dateContainer').text(dateText);
        console.log(dateText);
        $("#showDateItem").hide();
        }
        
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>



<div id="showDateContainer" type="button" >Click here to Shown Date</div>
<div id="showDateItem"> </div>
<br />
<br />
<div id="dateContainer" type="button" > currentData </div>
```

***Hoping this will help you :)***